# Why Xcode can not find a standard lib?

Tags: c++, xcode, oop, iostream

I've just installed os Catalina and updated xcode to current version.

I've tried

> xcode-select --install
>
> brew update

in cmd.

The thing is that program compiles but [an annoying error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bdIV2.jpg):

> 'iostream' file not found

How can I solve this?

Comment: Can you rephrase to ask an actual question?

Comment: Let me reword the question for you: *Why XCode can not find a standard lib?*

Comment: [You're not the only one](https://www.reddit.com/r/MacOS/comments/deojbw/xcode_11_iostream_file_not_found/f328ak1/).

Comment: I've edited the question so hopefully it's more clear for people.

Comment: Thank you for the edit!

Comment: If you're going through the trouble to install Xcode, I've found it's best to also start it up at least once and allow it to install the command line tools itself. My VS Code is still working on Catalina, so unfortunately I have no insights short of nuking the install. Could be worth checking the preferences and making sure that some command line tools are selected.